# how to recreate npm links to executables

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to npm and nodejs. I installed nodejs 9 and I created my first npm build app.

I noticed the `prefix` of npm was `/usr` and I changed it to `/usr/local/npm-global`

I moved the old packages to the new location. I wanted to recreate the symbolic links. How do i do that?

I checked `bin`, `link` and `rebuild` commands but the don't seem to be what I'm looking for.